# Check if restkit connection != nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, restkit

I fire a new request in

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

i.e. when I enter a text in the textfield, I send a new request.

```
ObjectMapping* mapping=[[ObjectMapping alloc]init];
RKResponseDescriptor* responseDescriptor=[mapping rkObjectMappingforAutoSuggest:baseURL];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[self.objectManager getObjectsAtPath:path
                          parameters:dictionary
                             success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                          }
                             failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Actually when I type the second text, I want to cancel the ongoing request, if exist, and I have to fire a new request.

I have no idea how to check if the connection is in process

Simply I wanna do

```
if(self.connection!=nil){ //cancel if in process
        [self.connection cancel];
    }
```

with rest kit environment. Kindly share your ideas..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check for a connection, simply call:

```
[self.objectManager cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodGET matchingPathPattern:path];
```

- assuming that `path` is a plain path without injected parameters